# How are you supposed to get a oAuth code if the user does not know your google play account?

Tags: php, android, server, backend

I am getting confused with the way oAuth works. I am currently using oAuth on a server side script to check if a google play receipt is valid.

To do this:
application sends requests to my script -> script exchanges code for access token -> script calls googles api with access token -> script then returns back data.

My question is, the only way to get the code is when you click "allow access" on your google play account after a redirect to get the code in the url. How is my script supposed to get my code automatically? Further more, the only way I can googles API is with a code for my developer account, obviously a user does not have access to that. How can I allow the script to get a code without the need to press "allow access"?

Comment: The trick is saving and using the "Refresh token". The "code" is only sent once when user clicks "allow access" but when you're replacing it for the first time, Google also replies with this "Refresh token" which has infinite lifetime (unlike the "Access token" which lives only 1hr).

Comment: Thank you so much!! You might want to put that as a answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: just did, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is saving and using the "Refresh token". The "code" is only sent once when user clicks "allow access" but when you're replacing it for the first time, Google also replies with this "Refresh token" which has infinite lifetime (unlike the "Access token" which lives only 1hr).